# According to Shastras,which deity is most known for bestowing material pleasures?

Tags: gods

Because Shastras in general, material pleasures are shunned and spiritual values are praised. For instance it is believed Sri Vishnu and His avatars are usually known for only bestowing spiritual boons while shunning material attachment and pleasures (some exceptions exist). Similarly Lord Shiva fulfills spiritual boons of His devotees. My question is more about material boons. Since most material boons are given by sadhnas of Yakshas,Gandharvas,Apsaras,Pisachas etc. I want to know if any particular deity is also known for bestowing material boon on His/Her devotees.

Comment: Kamadeva is the answer.

Comment: You already said it right. The result of sadhanas of Yaksha/Yakshini, Apasara (and similar deities) is always all types of material pleasures.